# Cancelling long-running Elasticsearch tasks times out

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, health-check, elasticsearch-exception

My `_search` requests had been gradually becoming slower and slower to the point of 504 gateway timeouts. Then I saw dozens of super-long running `indices:data/read/search` tasks with no end in sight so I tried to cancel them using `POST _tasks/_cancel?actions=*search` (note that I only have one node of interest so I didn't need the `&node=...` param).

This only resulted in another (`cancel`) task being registered and now even my `GET _tasks` and `GET _cat/tasks?v` requests are timing out.

I'm wondering whether it's possible to

1. set a cap on the `running_time_in_nanos` attribute of all `search` tasks and/or auto-cancel all the exceeding ones
2. force-cancel the tasks **without** having to restart the ES service when the Tasks API itself is timing out

Side note: I already have a health-check bash script

```
if [ `curl -s -m 20 https://my-es-instance | grep "You Know, for Search" | wc -l` -ne 1 ];
then
  echo "`date "+%F %T"` app not responding" &>> $my_log_file
  ...
```

but it doesn't take into consideration the fact that while the root (`GET /`) may be running, the `_search` endpoints are not.

What are the best practices here?

Comment: Any chance to get some `_nodes/stats` data when you see things slowing down? Something must be clearly undersized if you come to the point of having to restart regularly... Such a thing should never have to happen.

Comment: The last thing I noticed was free `mem` < 5%... Now I cannot even get `_nodes/stats`. That times out too.

Comment: How much RAM does your host have, how much heap did you allocate to ES and how much data is indexed?

Comment: I've requested this info from the devops folks and will get back to you. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Here are my nodes stats: https://gist.github.com/jzzfs/2f0c0e8a639803c7dae1e93b63e2b9bb, 25GB RAM in total, 6GB heap if I'm not mistaken. Here are my _cat/indices: https://gist.github.com/jzzfs/b3f3fa0e05884c62523c600b37fed36b --> ~1M top-level docs but there's some deep nestedness which is required for my quite complicated aggs which turn out to be very memory intensive. Hardly any CPU load.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. Now let's wait until your cluster gets overloaded again and take the nodes stats again. I think I know where this is coming from. Another question, do you have anything else running on that node, and if not, why didn't you dedicate half the total RAM to the ES heap as advised?

Comment: I think heap was assigned in absolute amounts and then total RAM was increased... Also, I think the server is not dedicated to just ES and there are other production systems running. Don't ask why I'm not in control of that ... BTW I'm encountering the stuck-tasks issue again. Used RAM is hovering around 92%, heap around 16%. Here's the tasks list https://gist.github.com/jzzfs/2813f8f6b8cae4a5e035b89a625d82b6

Comment: Can you get the nodes stats again and also `GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults` please?

Comment: Cluster: https://gist.github.com/jzzfs/44cf5eae21365a6277cd4fa13aaf92c6, Nodes: https://gist.github.com/jzzfs/aba1ace485a51ef7e004cec655c9d7d8

Comment: Thanks! Any chance to get `GET /_nodes/hot_threads` too?

Comment: And last thing, the node stats just after the restart the node, to compare with baseline values

Comment: Here are the hot threads: https://gist.github.com/jzzfs/2a83478b32291f1de95e8f361735e1a3. You can consider the first node_stats gist to be the baseline -- the tasks list was empty at that time.

Comment: Thanks, but hot threads is almost empty, correct? so there was approximately one hour between both node stats. That's how long your node stands up, right?

Comment: Yes, that's all I found. TBH I haven't looked into them yesterday so can't tell whether they played a role. What do you mean by the node "standing up"? I mean, it's functioning quite okay now but I know if I keep requesting mem-heavy search loads, the tasks queue will fill up and a restart will be necessary.

Comment: I meant that whenever you get heavy queries you node starts being non-responsive and eventually you have to restart it. So I take note that it's not depending on a time duration, but simply on usage. From what I see in the numbers, I would clearly at least double the heap available to ES, you clearly have memory intensive queries and 6GB don't seem to cut it.

Comment: If heap memory can't be increased, another axis to explore would be to optimize your mapping and queries

Comment: Got it, I'll try increasing the heap. I wonder how I can debug the stuck tasks more closely? Or set a cap on the permitted running time? Any ideas in that direction please?

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: That's good. `6.8.5`

Comment: You could probably start specifying a [`timeout`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) in your search queries, so that they get cancelled if they run for too long. Also `terminate_after` to get results, no matter whether finished or not, after a certain time, but that doesn't work for aggregations, only for hits

Comment: I'm adding the timeout -- that should help. The heap will be increased next week...

Comment: my devops folks are saying the following: the JVM memory is set to 6G, because the OS also needs RAM for caching https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/heap-size.html

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If there's 25GB of RAM in total, you can give up to 12GB to the heap without a problem, that's exactly what that link says (`no more than 50% of your physical RAM, to ensure that there is enough physical RAM left for kernel file system caches.`)... that's double the size you have now

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks